# image download in zip using java

Tags: java, image

I am trying to download image as zip , but when i am trying to run the below code it says "Compressed Folder is invalid" when i try opening the folder unsing 7zip or any other zip extractor. Please help

```
      public static void main(String[] args) {
    FileOutputStream fos;
    try {
        fos = new FileOutputStream("D:\\update.zip");

        ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(fos);
         URL url = new URL("http://n3.sdlcdn.com/imgs/b/9/r/SDL468499912_2-8f209.jpg");

        ZipEntry ze = new ZipEntry(url.getFile());
        zos.putNextEntry(ze);
        byte[] data = new byte[300000];
        //   fos.write(data, 0, data.length);
        zos.write(data, 0, data.length);
        zos.closeEntry();
        zos.finish();
        zos.close();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Main77.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3428396/how-to-save-images-into-a-zip-file

Comment: You only writed 300000 blanks in the file which is not a real Image.

Answer (score 0):

Save Images to zip as follows.

```
public class ZipSaveWorker implements Runnable{

public static ZipOutputStream out=null;
BufferedImage myImage;
private static int counter=0;



public void run() {
    ZipEntry entry=new ZipEntry("video"+counter+".jpg");
    counter++;
    try {
        out.putNextEntry(entry);
        ImageIO.write(myImage, "jpg", out);

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ZipSaveWorker.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}

public ZipSaveWorker(BufferedImage image)
{
    if (out==null)
    {
        try {
            out = new ZipOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File("images" + File.separator + "video.zip"))));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ZipSaveWorker.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        counter=0;
    }

    myImage=image;

}

public static void closeStream()
{
    try {
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ZipSaveWorker.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
}
```

And Download Images using any Imagedownload libarary

Comment: i tried using  BufferedImage myImage = ImageIO.read(new URL("http://n3.sdlcdn.com/imgs/b/9/r/SDL468499912_2-8f209.jpg"));
            ZipSaveWorker zip = new ZipSaveWorker(myImage);
            zip.run(); ... but the output zip file is coming of 0 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

zos.write is writing blank buffer of byte array.

```
        byte[] data = new byte[300000];

          zos.write(data, 0, data.length);
```

Why don't you initialise a smaller byte array and loop through actual bytes received in the downloaded image to add in the output stream?

See a good example of using zip output stream at http://www.java-examples.com/create-zip-file-directory-using-zipoutputstream-example

Read the image data in byte array and add the bytes to zipoutputstream.